# Отправка простого запроса на сервер раз в 3 секунды

Tags: apache, php

Идея такова, мне нужно быть постоянно онлайн в одном вебсервисе, но желания держать комп включенным целый день желания нет. Чтобы быть онлайн мне достаточно посылать на сервер простой запрос раз в 3 сек  и он будет думать что я онлайн.
Собственно вопрос: возможно ли это реализовать на PHP?

То есть я захожу запускаю `index.php`, а он (именно серверная часть,а не клиентская) в бесконечном цикле посылает `webrequest` к заданному серверу. 
На сколько это реализуемо?

Comment: А как ты будешь отсылать постоянно запрос если ты выключишь комп?

Comment: идея в том что сервер никогда не вернет страницу, он будет в бесконечном цикле кода php посылать запрос к другому серверу. 
Получается я перешел по ссылке - тем самым запустил скрипт и все
мне сервер не ответил, но он работает на страницей. Или там есть таймайут какой-то?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Почему нет? Вполне реализуемо, `set_time_limit(0)` и вперед, только сервер все равно нужен будет ;)

Ну и порекомендовал бы как-то сделать, чтобы можно было выключать этот сервис, может быть еще подумать о защите от запуска параллельных этих "сервисов", но это уже другое ;)

Answer (score 0):

Для исполнения скрипта, тебе однозначно потребуется включенная машина. Отправка запроса на другие веб ресурсы через php вполне возможна, это дело тройки строк кода. Вообще, если там GET запросы то можно вообще на javascript